# Get location coordinates using opentripplanner geocoder

Tags: java, http, geocoding, opentripplanner

I installed opentripplanner and want to use its geocoder to get coordinates by location name. However, I neither found any info of how to use it nor any examples.

Could someone provide an request to geocoder example or share a link with API usage tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the solution [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44640/using-geocoder-of-opentripplanner/75721#75721).

Also if you want want to use its geocoder to get coordinates by location name then just change the url to `localhost:8080/otp-geocoder/geocode/?address=Pune`